# MySQL order by bigger ID

Tags: php, mysql

How do you put an order from the biggest to lowest?

I'm using:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM builds 
                    WHERE approved = 'yes' AND ORDER BY build_id LIMIT 0, 10");
```

but im geting this error:

```
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\pcbuilds\index.php on line 9
```

Any way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

your query looks wrong , you have AND alone.remove that AND

```
  SELECT * FROM builds 
                WHERE approved = 'yes'  ORDER BY build_id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `desc` keyword to get the order from the biggest to the lowest:

```
SELECT *
FROM builds 
WHERE approved = 'yes'
ORDER BY build_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```